# Adding a URL parameter to an OmniAuth Stratery

Tags: facebook, devise, omniauth

When connecting using the Facebook strategy, I want to use display=popup in the Facebook URL.

I saw that the initialiize() function has an options argument, where can I call it 
outside the Omniauth gem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I have mine setup:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :facebook, 'YOUR_APP_ID', 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY', :display => 'popup'
end
```